# How to pass a dynamic number of elements to a Method which accepts a ParamArray

Tags: vb.net, paramarray

I have a method which I need to call which accepts a ParamArray

```
Method(ByVal ParamArray elements() As Object)
```

I need to pass it two known strings, and an unknown number of strings, based on a variable  number of XmlNodes in an XmlDocument

i.e.

```
Method("Known String 1", "Known String 2", Node1.OuterXml, ..., NodeN.OuterXml)
```

How can I do this?

I have tried looping through the nodes and creating and passing:

`List(Of String)` which results in `elements()` containing `"Known String 1", "Known String 2", System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]`

`List(Of String).ToArray` which results in `elements()` containing `"Known String 1", "Known String 2", System.String[]`

`String()` which results in `elements()` containing `"Known String 1", "Known String 2", System.String[]`

and

`Collection` which results in `elements()` containing `"Known String 1", "Known String 2", Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`

What I want, for an example of 3 nodes is `elements()` to contain `"Known String 1", "Known String 2", "<node 1>", "<node 2>", "<node 3>"`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the nonintuitive leap between what you write and what the compiler does - mainly because the syntax is a little wonky.

Anyhow, notice that your method signature contains a SINGLE parameter: `elements()`.  The `()` means its an array.

The `ParamArray` keyword allows you to "explode" the elements of an array and pass each array element as its own parameter to the method - something you already knew.  But it also means that the compiler (or JIT, or whatever) recombines those parameters back into a single array.

You would have noticed this if you hadn't had the misfortune of defining `elements` as `Object`:

so **TL;DR**:
Either pass each array element individually - not an option in your case,
Or pass a single array in for the array-typed parameter.

Dim stuffToPassInToTheMethod As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {"Magic String One", "Magic String Two"}

' Some loops and xml nodes.. blah blah..  end up calling stuffToPassInToTheMethod.Add(node.Attributes("yadda").Value

Then finally just pass it to the method:  `crazyMethodNameWithThePOINTLESSParamArray(stuffToPassInToTheMethod.ToArray)`

Answer (score -1):

My answer so far is to check the types in the method and add the values to a new List(Of String) and then work with the list, not the object array:

```
    Dim strElements As New List(Of String)        

    For Each element As Object In elements
        If element.GetType Is GetType(System.String) Then
            strElements.Add(element)
        ElseIf element.GetType Is GetType(System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)) Then
            For Each s As String In element
                strElements.Add(s)
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

But if there is a better way to add the individual strings to the ParamArray directly that would be much better

Comment: And when you can't modify the method and only seeks that the paramarray works with the syntax?

Answer (score -2):

Shevek's answer works great.  All you have to do is then pass the list you've created/populated to the method expecting a parmarray as "strElements.ToArray".  I just used this to populate a DataGridView with a dynamic number of columns, like this (in a loop, creating a new strElements list for each row of data):  dgvData.Rows.Add(strElements.ToArray)